# Using Portlet Unit with JSR 168 Specification Portlets

Tags: junit, websphere, portlet, ibm-rad, jsr168

We are moving to a testing based development approach. We are looking towards [PortletUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portletunit/) as our unit testing aid for testing the Portlets.

1. I have included all the Portlet Unit jars into the project
2. Created a test case and added a testing method to test the doView functionality.

While I have followed the steps in the documentation I got an exception at the following point.

```
File webInfDir=new File("C:/Test_168_Portlet/WebContent");
Class portletClass = Test_168_Portlet.class;
PortletRunner runner = null;
runner = PortletRunner.createPortletRunner(portletClass,webInfDir, "Test_168_Portlet");
```

The exception states:

> javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization of one or more
>   services failed.

Comment: Need more information on the services that failed to initialize. Please post the whole stack trace.